# For plug in running on iOS

Tags: ios, plugins

What I want to implement is as follow:

A-app (calling app) : request the return value of a-string sent as parameter : request(a-string) -> b-string.

B-app (plug-in installed separately by me or others, it plays the role of dictionary or database ) : search a-string from database and return the result (b-string).

With successful experiences of plug-in on android and with Apple's confident rhetoric of plug-in, I thought plug-in, of course, run on iOS. After a lot of hard work, however, I finally found out:

*** Note : The creation and use of loadable bundles is not supported in iOS.***

Nonetheless, not giving up, I finally made it with custom URl and pasteboard:

A-app : write a-string and false state to pasteboard & call B-app via custom URL.

B-app : viewDidLoad runs following func and thereafter exit program ; func { read pasteboard and search from database & write the result(b-string) and true state to pasteboard }

A-app : while-loop detects whether state is false or true. if true, catch b-string from pasteboard.

Anyway it works but it's too long thus almost useless. Do you have any idea for better solutions? Why doesn't Apple allow plug-in for iOS? Any responses are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why Apple doesn't allow plug-ins, but I can offer some advice on what you're trying to achieve.

The common pattern for sending data back to your application is to implement a callback url, so the A-app would also implement a custom URI and add that to the uri sent to B-app.
B-app would then process the uri as you have already implemented, but then instead of exiting, it simply sends the data you requested in the uri passed to it.

See http://x-callback-url.com for more details and example implementations.

Comment: Thanks to NigelG. That's a good website for a good scheme. I am sorry my vote cannot be reflected. When it comes to the above issue, the critical point is the time gap between B-app appears after A-app disappears and A-app appears again after B-app disappears. This problem presumedly cannot be solved under custom URL framework.

Comment: Another flaw is it is difficult to App Extension. The best way is Apple changes his mind, I think. Thank you anyhow.